# mobile model number detection in php

Tags: php, mysql, css, html

I am a PHP developer and desisgning a WAP page for mobiles.I need some php code to find out the model of a mobile phone from where request is coming so that based on that information I can upload the proper CSS for my page.If you can give me some hints as well that would also help me to proceed further.Currently I am able to fetch user-agent of mobile but not able to find out the specific model of mobile.

Comment: Perhaps by looking at the [user agent](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Mobile%20Browserlist/)?

Comment: here a php class exactly do same what for you looking http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/wiki/Mobile_Detect

Comment: I can detect android and java phone but i cant detect china phone having mre application so need some help for it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

Check it against this list of user agents:
http://techpatterns.com/forums/about304.html (starting from ~line343 to ~line610)

Comment: I can detect android and java phone but i cant detect china phone having mre application so need some help for it. Thanks

Comment: Sorry that is the only list I know of, it includes **most** user agent strings... but not **all**.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using mobile_detect class
It has methods you can use, such as `isiPhone()`, `isBlackberry()` , `isSamsung()` etc..

Note that however it's very hard or almost impossible to find the model number, but finding the brand is possible.

Comment: Also wrapper methods such as "isMobile", and even "isTablet" for if you don't need to be so specific.

Comment: I can detect android and java phone but i cant detect china phone having mre application so need some help for it. Thanks

Comment: Does mobiledetect allow you to get the phone brand? ie $brand = $detect_brand() or something it seems that you need to know the brand beforehand like isSamsung()